# Convert Number to Date type in oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have 19980215 value in number type.
I want to convert it to date type like (1998/02/15).
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you use the `TO_DATE` function to convert it into a date.

```
select to_date(19980215, 'yyyymmdd')
  from ...
```

And then you can use TO_CHAR to display it in a format of your choice.

```
select to_char(to_date(19980215, 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
  from ...
```

Comment: I would rather avoid implicit type conversion and do like this: `to_date(to_char(19980215), 'yyyymmdd')`.

Comment: I'm aware of several ways to screw up implicit type conversion between varchar -> date. But even after some thinking, I can't come up with a single example where it would make a difference with yet another TO_CHAR? I suppose what you mean is `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(<number>), ...`

Comment: Surely I was meaning `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(<number>), ...`, sorry for not being clear on this. My point was that such question is more likely asked by novice database users. And it is good time for them to get a good habit not to use implicit conversions at all. Used to write code that way they will escape many problems in the future. Of course there are cases where it makes no difference and both expressions work pretty same.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [to_date()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132) function:

```
select to_char(to_date(19980215,'yyyymmdd'),'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual
```